# stockSymbols doesn't return key variables

Tags: r

I wrote a code in R, which is based on stockSymbols(). It normally returned several key parameters but now suddenly key parameters are returned as NA. These are: IPOyear, Sector, Industry.
Anyone has an idea why has it been changed or not returned? 
And an alternative option would be greatly appreciated. I need to retrieve all Nasdaq, AMEX, NYSE tickers including their market cap, industry and sector.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the details, but often such changes are due to licensing issues. It may be necessary to resort to commercial data providers.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that it's more related to the relevant R package itself (TTR) rather than the providers. All the other data still appears.

Answer (score 0):

ok, just got it. Seems like an issue with the NASDAQ site itself as it doesn't publish those parameters from some reason. Probably no issue with the function itself ..

Comment: I don't think it's related to licensing issues. Anyone who browses Nasdaq.com now will get the same fault. It's an issue with their site.Probably they will fix it sometime.